# TinyMCE 6.* - apply new options after init, init_instance_callback, setup

Tags: javascript, tinymce

Is there a way, for the new 6.* version, to set options on the running instance? Before, we could use something like:
editor.settings.toolbar = ' ....... ', but now it doesn't work at all. Also new API editor.options.set(....) change options, but it doesn't reflect to running instance. How can I set new options for running instances?

I tried to use callbacks on init - "init_instance_callback" and "setup" and set options there (as mentioned above), but also have no effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
// first you should get the editor by its id
let editor = tinymce.get('tiny-editor');

// then you should register the option you want to change 
// and set the type of its value, here I change save_onsavecallback option
// which will be a function, all types you can find here: 
// https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/tinymce/6/apis/tinymce.editoroptions/
editor.options.register('save_onsavecallback', {
    processor: 'function'
});

// and at last you change the option
editor.options.set('save_onsavecallback', function () {
    ...
});
```